# Zero crossing circuit with phase control

Tags: mains, comparator, zero-crossing

Beginner here.

I am trying to make a "zero crossing" circuit with phase control. This is probably not the right name for the circuit.

Basically, I have a sine wave (from the power outlet) at more or less 60Hz, and I want to be able to generate a trigger signal at any point of the sinewave exactly like you would do in a scope.
Here is what I came up with, I use an op amp like a comparator between the sine wave and I change the value to which I compare with (V+) using resistors: [image]

In this circuit Vin would be the output of a transformer connecting to the power outlet. My idea is that R1 and R7 would be a potentiometer that I would turn to modify the voltage at the non inverting input of the op amp, and by changing that voltage I change the level at which the op amp rails so that it generates a valid trigging signal.
For example, when R1= 10k and R7=0, I get: [image]
On the other hand, when R1= 0 and R7=10k, I get:[image]

I think this kind of works because you can see from the vertical dashed bars that the relative position of the rising edge changes. However, I do not really like the fact that the slope of the rising edge changes, the fact that the output is never at 0V and also I think it is a bit hard to reliably trig on the top of the sine wave like this, because I need to be on the very edge of the potentiometer with R1 almost 0.

Q: How can I make this better? Is there some standard circuit to do this?

Comment: Trigger a variable monoflop at the zero crossing, then the timing of the trigger does not depend on the AC voltage.

Comment: I will look at what a monoflop is

Comment: It is a triggered timer or delay like e.g. NE555.

Comment: Use a capacitor on input so any DC offset is ignored.